# Show loader on Ajax.BeginForm submit

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to show a loader and disable the button when we submit a form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(MVC.Account.Login(), new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onLoginSuccess" }, new { @id = "loginForm" }))
{
  <div id="logbtn">
    <input type="submit" name="invisible" class="subinvisible"/> 
    <p>@HeelpResources.AccountLoginViewLoginButtonLabel</p>
    <img src="~/Content/Images/ui-symb-arrow-right-white-15x15.png" width="13" height="12" />
  </div>
}
```

The loader image file is

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/ui-loader-white-16x16.gif" />
```

Maybe using the OnBegin from the BeginForm to show the loader and the OnComplete to hide-it? But how can I change the image?

Any sugestion to find nice quality free loaders?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Put your loading image tag inside a div tag like this:

```
<div id="loading">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/ui-loader-white-16x16.gif" />
</div>
```

In your CSS file:

```
div#loading { display: none; }
```

And, in your form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(MVC.Account.Login(), 
  new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onLoginSuccess", LoadingElementId = "loading", 
    OnBegin = "onLoginBegin" }, 
  new { @id = "loginForm" }))
{
  <div id="logbtn">
    <input type="submit" name="invisible" class="subinvisible"/> 
    <p>@HeelpResources.AccountLoginViewLoginButtonLabel</p>
    <img src="~/Content/Images/ui-symb-arrow-right-white-15x15.png" width="13" height="12" />
  </div>
}
```

And, add a script to your View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoginBegin()
    { 
        // Disable the button and hide the other image here 
        // or you can hide the whole div like below
        $('#logbtn').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! But where do you put the loading image? and how do you replace the ui-symb-arrow-right-white-15x15.png image with the loader?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You put the loading image inside a hidden div. And, use the id of the hidden div as LoadingElementId in your ajax form. 

In order to hide the other image and disable the button, you can use the OnBegin property of the AjaxOptions class. Look at the updated answer.